# MongoDB ifNull on lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out how to do the following:

I currently use the following script to see if an advert matches a listing.

```
'$lookup': {
                'from': 'advertisers', 
                'localField': 'title', 
                'foreignField': 'title', 
                'as': 'adsys'
            }
```

but some of our listings don't have adverts and when it is currently returning it is showing adsys:[]

Instead I would like it to ether show adsys:NULL or remove the adsys completely. I have looked at

```
$ifNull
```

However I am unsure how I attach it to the adsys if it's in the lookup.

I tried this:

```
 {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'advertisers', 
                'localField': 'title', 
                'foreignField': 'title', 
                'as': 'adsys'
            }
        },
        {
                '$project': {
                   'title': 1,
                   'adsys': { '$ifNull': [ "$adsys", "Unspecified" ] }
                }
             }
```

and it returned this:

```
{"data":[{"track":[{"_id":"5e1a96c3081a7a70d5c8971f","title":"Out of Mind","adsys":[]}]}]}
```

what I would like it to do is return this

```
 {"data":[{"track":[{"_id":"5e1a96c3081a7a70d5c8971f","title":"Out of Mind","adsys":NULL}]}]}
```

Comment: If `title` is an object of `track` which is in an object of `data` then how is that `title:1` working in `$project` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set null value using $unwind keyword after checking value of adsys and set null value if adsys is not defined.

```
db.tableName.aggregate(
    [
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'advertisers',
                'localField': 'title',
                'foreignField': 'title',
                'as': 'adsys'
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": { path: "$adsys", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
        {
            '$project': {
                'title': 1,
                'adsys': { '$ifNull': ["$adsys", "NULL"] }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: well this would work, but there can be issues in few cases(which might be most cases) - 1) If the result has huge dataset `$unwind` is not a good option, 2) If `title` in `listing` document has multiple matches in `advertisers` then `adsys` will have more than one object(n num of matching objects) - So doing `$unwind` & then grouping those back to form the original result document will be tedious. Basically this will help if result data is less & `adsys` has either `[]` or exactly one object `[{}]` :-)

Comment: Also in `$project` you don't need this `'adsys': { '$ifNull': ["$adsys", "NULL"] }` as after `$unwind` you won't see `adsys` if it's `[]` as it will be removed -O/P's another ask..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this as the end stage :

```
{$project : {'title' :1, 'adsys' : {$cond : [{$gt:[{$size: '$adsys'}, 0]}, '$adsys' , null ] }}}
```

So your query would be :

```
{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'advertisers',
        'localField': 'title',
        'foreignField': 'title',
        'as': 'adsys'
    }
}, { $project: { 'title': 1, 'adsys': { $cond: [{ $gt: [{ $size: '$adsys' }, 0] }, '$adsys', null] } } }
```

** Sample Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1aa8d5627ef782369ef777"),
    "title" : "Out of Mind",
    "adsys" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1aa8e1627ef782369ef854"),
    "title" : "Out of Mind",
    "adsys" : [ 
        {
            "abc" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1aa8d5627ef782369ef777"),
    "title" : "Out of Mind",
    "adsys" : null
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1aa8e1627ef782369ef854"),
    "title" : "Out of Mind",
    "adsys" : [ 
        {
            "abc" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```